# Count occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: vb6

Looking for the best way to do this in VB6. Typically, I would use this approach...

```
   ' count spaces
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        If Mid$(text, i, 1) = " " Then count = count + 1 
    Next
```

Comment: Do you want to count spaces or distinct characters?

Comment: what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: So are you looking to count unique characters or specific characters?  Your title suggests 'unique', your sample suggests 'specific'.

Comment: The only thing I would add is to move the Len(text) OUTSIDE the For, saving it in a variable.

Comment: @xanatos - VB6 strings are [stored in BSTR format](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html), so the length function is O(1), so it's only a minor optimization.  The compiler would likely get it.

Comment: I want to count a specific character in a string even though my example is using a space.

Comment: @Scott I knew, but you can't optimize much else of the code :-) Unless count or text are variant :-) :-)

Comment: @xanatos - true, though it's probably faster to compare ascii values than literal strings.  Plus, the author's comment just changed the nature of the question... arg

Comment: To answer Beth's question, I recently went from being member of a mid size dev team to being a lone-wolf responsible to keep a project going.  I miss having smart people review my solution to a problem.  I enjoy learning from others.  Stackoverflow is a great substitute!

Comment: @xanatos @scott VB only evaluates the `To` expression once anyway. It's a `For` loop, not a `Do While` loop.

Comment: @garykindel: I changed your question title, the title and what you are acually asking didn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a modified bucket sort:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim index As Integer
Dim count as Integer
Dim FoundByAscii(0 To 255) As Boolean
For i = 1 To Len(text)
    index = Asc(Mid$(text, i, 1))
    FoundByAscii(index) = True
Next i
count = 0
For i = 0 To 255
    If FoundByAscii(i) Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i
```

...and your result is in `count`.  The performance is O(N) - if `Mid$` is O(1).

**Edit**:

Based on your clarification, do this:

```
   ' count spaces
    Dim asciiToSearchFor As Integer
    asciiToSearchFor = Asc(" ")
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        If Asc(Mid$(text, i, 1)) = asciiToSearchFor Then count = count + 1 
    Next
```

As ascii compares have to be faster that string comparison.  I'd profile it just in case, but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Very Nice answer!  Even though, I did not state ASCII as a requirement, I like the idea of limiting my search a specific character range.  Turns out my problem would fit this solution nicely.

Comment: I'd guess `AscW` will be even faster, since VB6 strings are Unicode internally

Answer (score 21):

Not saying it's the best way, but you code do:

```
distinctChr = " "
count = Len(text) - Len(Replace(text, distinctChr , ""))
```

Comment: I like the terse approach on this answer.

Comment: This became a better answer once the question changed.  :)

Comment: beautiful example of duct-tape-programming ( https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2009/09/23/the-duct-tape-programmer/ ) . Like it a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Use the split command like this

```
Dim TempS As String
TempS = " This is a split  test "
Dim V As Variant
V = Split(TempS, " ")
Cls
Print UBound(V) '7
V = Split(TempS, "i")
Print UBound(V) '3
V = Split(TempS, "e")
Print UBound(V) '1
```

You can combine it to a single line.

```
Print UBound(Split(TempS, "i"))
```

I did some crude timing on it. On a 40,000 character string with all spaces it seems to clock in at 17 milliseconds on a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 processor.

A function could look like this

```
Function CountChar(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Char As String) As Long
    Dim V As Variant
    V = Split(Text, Char)
    CountChar = UBound(V)
End Function
```

Comment: I liked this answer too. If I could accept two answers for a question, I would accept your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by the *best* way to do this.

If you want something *very* fast, but *totally* unmaintainable, adapt this [horrible code](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_WordCount.htm#WordCount11) that delves into the underlying memory of a VB6 string to count the number of words. Courtesy of [VBspeed](http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed).