# Using Ms Access VBA, how do I check the value of a variable to see if it has a value other than "', "

Tags: vba, string

I have a variable with a string...and I want to know if it contains any value other than single quote, comma and a space  ("', ") I'm using vba in excel.

for example, i have a varible strA = "'test', 'player'"
I want to check to see if strA has any characters other than "', " (single quote, comma and space).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a strategy based on [Count occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314729/count-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)
I don't have vba handy, but this should work. The idea is to remove all these characters and see if anything is left. `text` represents your string that is being tested.

```
Dim TempS As String
TempS = Replace(text, " " , "")
TempS = Replace(TempS, "," , "")
TempS = Replace(TempS, "'" , "")
```

and your result is `Len(TempS>0)`

Another approach is to use recursion by having a base case of false if the string is empty, if the first character is one of the three call ourselves on the rest of the string, or if not the value is true. Here is the code

```
 function hasOtherChars(s As String) As Boolean
 hasOtherChars=false
 if (len(s)=0) then
   exit function
 end if
 Dim asciiSpace As Integer
    asciiSpace = Asc(" ")
    Dim asciiComma As Integer
    asciiComma= Asc(",")
    Dim asciiApostrophe As Integer
    asciiApostrophe = Asc("'")
 Dim c as Integer
 c = Asc(Mid$(s, 1, 1))
 if ((c=asciiSpace) or (c=asciiComma) or (c=asciiApostrophe)) then
    hasOtherChars = hasOtherChars(Mid$(s,2))
else
 hasOtherChars=true
 end if
End function
```

Again I am borrowing from the other thread.

Comment: note the other methods there could also be adapted for this purpose. Recursion would also be an option long the lines of if empty string, false else if the first char is not one of those 3 true, else whatever it is for the function called on the rest of the string.